# Is it possible to cache static files that are gzip compressed in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, caching, compression, gzip

Below gzip compression is used by using the popular [npm compression package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression).

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.use(compression())
```

Many static files are unnecessarily compressed every time like static images. Is there perhaps a package that uses some form of cache so as not to compress the same file over and over again?